# Python: better to use dictionary or hashmap for common elements of array

Tags: python, algorithm

I have to find list of common numbers from 2 unordered lists.
I have 2 approaches. 
Can someone explain which one is better and why

```
def common_by_dictionary(a1,a2):
    d1 = {}
    for i in a1:
        if not(i in d1):
            d1[i]=1
    for i in a2:
        if (i in d1):
            d1[i]=0
    c = []
    for i in d1:
        if(d1[i]==0):
            c.append(i)
    print c

def common_by_hashmap(a1,a2):
    h = [0]*1000
    for i in a1:
        if not (i in h):
            h[i]=1
    c = []
    for i in a2:
        if(h[i]==1):
            c.append(i)
    print c



common_by_dictionary([1,3,4,6,7,9,12,5],[1,2,4,5,9,10,3])
common_by_hashmap([1,3,4,6,7,9,12,5],[1,2,4,5,9,10,3])
```

Comment: You aren't using a hashmap in `common_by_hashmap`, you are using a `list`, which is implemented as a dynamic array. Indeed, a `dict` is implemented as a hashmap, so you are using a hashmap in `common_by_dictionary`. The dictionary based approach is more performant than the list based approach. If you are going to use auxiliary storage, a `set` would be the most idiomatic approach, with similar performance characteristics as the dict-based approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `set`:

```
def common(first, second):
    return set(first) & set(second)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no hash map in python. A dictionary in essence is java equivalence of hash map. You're just using list(array) in in your `common_by_hashmap` function

Answer (score 0):

The first one is better. In the second one, this part:

```
    for i in a1:
        if not (i in h):
            h[i]=1
```

has O(N^2) complexity because `i in h` requires O(N) operations. Although in this case, the `N` might be a constant 1000, it is still significantly slower than querying a dict.

But IMO, the correct approach for your problem is using a set as pointed out by Lim:

```
def common_by_set(a1, a2):
    return list(set(a1) & set(a2))
```